# Proof that equality of derivative of section is coordinate independent

Tags: partial-derivative, jet-bundles

**Lemma 4.1.1** in D.J Saunders 's book (The geometry of jet bundles) says:

Let $(E,\pi,M)$ be a bundle, and let $p$ $\in M$. Suppose that
$\phi$ and $\psi$ are section that satisfy $\phi(p)=\psi(p)$. Let $(x^i,u^\alpha)$ and $(y^i,v^\beta)$ be two adapted
coordinate systems around $\phi(p)$, and suppose also that $$\frac{\partial( 
 u^\alpha \circ \phi)}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{p}=\frac{\partial( 
 u^\alpha \circ \psi)}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{p}$$
for $1 \leq i\leq m$ and $1 \leq \alpha \leq n$ then

$$\frac{\partial( 
 v^\beta \circ \phi)}{\partial y^i}\bigg|_{p}=\frac{\partial( 
 v^\beta \circ \psi)}{\partial y^i}\bigg|_{p}$$
for $1 \leq j\leq m$ and $1 \leq \beta \leq n$

To proof this he uses the relation

$$\frac{\partial( 
 v^\beta \circ \phi)}{\partial y^j}\bigg|_{p}=\frac{\partial( 
 v^\beta \circ \phi)}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{p} \frac{\partial 
 x^i }{\partial y^j}\bigg|_{p}=\left (\frac{\partial 
 v^\beta }{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\phi(p)}+\frac{\partial 
 v^\beta }{\partial u^{\alpha}}\bigg|_{\phi(p)} \frac{\partial( 
 u^\alpha \circ \phi)}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{p} \right)\frac{\partial 
 x^i }{\partial y^j}\bigg|_{p} \tag 1$$

What I am not seeing is why from $(1)$ we obtain
$$\frac{\partial( 
 v^\beta \circ \phi)}{\partial y^i}\bigg|_{p}=\frac{\partial( 
 v^\beta \circ \psi)}{\partial y^i}\bigg|_{p}$$
for $1 \leq j\leq m$ and $1 \leq \beta \leq n$

Comment: on the RHS of $(1)$ look at where $\phi$ appears. We have $\phi(p)$ in the bottom as a point of evaluation, but by assumption this is just $\psi(p)$. Next, you have $\frac{\partial(u^{\alpha}\circ \phi)}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p$, but again by assumption this is just $\frac{\partial(u^{\alpha}\circ \psi)}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p$. So, now everywhere on the RHS of (1) we have $\psi$'s only, so that is equal to $\frac{\partial(v^{\beta}\circ \psi)}{\partial y^j}\bigg|_p$.